# System.AccessViolationException while construct Mat using EmguCV

Tags: c#, emgucv, access-violation

what I need is an `Emgu.Cv.Mat`. Due to I have an `Bitmap` I want to pass his information to this Mat instance.

Here is my code:

```
//the real file is not stored on the harddrive. this is for demonstration only.
Bitmap fileBmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\my\Desktop\file1.PNG");
```

.

```
//generating an Image from it works pretty fine as well. Even displaying it works great.
Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(fileBmp);
```

.

```
//But I'm not able to generate a Mat with it. Not using the Bitmap
Mat mat1 = new Mat(new int[] { fileBmp.Width, fileBmp.Height }, DepthType.Cv8S, fileBmp.GetHbitmap());

//... and not using the Image
Mat mat2 = new Mat(new int[] { fileBmp.Width, fileBmp.Height }, DepthType.Cv8S, image.Bitmap.GetHbitmap());
```

I keep getting an

> System.AccessViolationException

If I read either `mat1.Bitmap` property or `mat2.Bitmap` property (all other properties looking fine).[image: error] What is wrong with my code?

Any suggestions how I can pass the "graphic information" to an `Mat` using `EmguCv`?

One again: using `new Mat(@"C:\Users\my\Desktop\file1.PNG")` is not possible due to the bitmap is not stored on the hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(fileBmp);
Mat mat1 = image.Mat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check to make sure you are compiling for x64 if you are using EmguCV 3.1